# ¿Por que, en Netbeans, al final de cada linea hay un caracter similar a una "q" (¶)?

Tags: netbeans

[image: Si se fijan cada vez que hago espacio me aparece el simbolo de una q al final, como quito esto]

Estoy utilizando Netbeans para trabajar un proyecto en Java, y me aparece un símbolo similar al de una "q" (¶) al final de cada linea. ¿Cómo quito esto?

Comment: Eso no es una letra invisible, es un objeto no imprimible que indica salto de párrafo (es como en Word por ejemplo y otros IDEs o procesadores de texto). Generalmente eso se quita yendo al menú `View` y desmarcando una opción llamada `Show non printable objects` o `Show invisible characters` o `Hide invisible characters` o algo parecido. No sé exactamente cómo viene en Netbeans.

Comment: Cuanto mal no habrá hecho ya el NetBeans...

Comment: No estoy 100% seguro, pero creo que el nombre del caracter utilizado para mostrar un "Carriage Return" es [Calderon](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calder%C3%B3n_(tipograf%C3%ADa)).

Answer (score 6):

No es una cuestión de Java, es una cuestión de cómo se codifican los archivos de texto.

Al fin y al cabo, un archivo es una sucesión de bytes. Un archivo de texto simplemente tiene los carácteres codificados de una determinada forma, están los carácteres visibles (espacios, letras, etc.) y otros "invisibles" que no se representan como texto (como, por ejemplo, los carácteres que indican el fin de línea).

Muchos editores te dan la opción de "mostrar" u "ocultar" estos carácteres especiales.

En [esta pregunta del sitio en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23425376/how-to-remove-strange-reverse-p-character-at-end-of-line) te muestra como ocultar esos carácteres; básicamente ir al menú "View" y hacer click en "Show Non-Printable objects".

Eso no los eliminará (están en el archivo; es como se marca que allí hay un fin de línea) pero no te mostrará el símbolo raro.

Answer (score 4):

Es una configuración de NetBeans, para quitarlo has lo siguiente:

1. Abre NetBeans
2. Ve al menu "View" en la parte superor
3. Elimina la marca en la opción "Show Non-Printable Characters".

Answer (score 3):

Eso se puede configurar.

[image: opción Show Non-printable Characters en menú view]

Es una caracteristica que istóricamente tenía muchos problemas, si necesitas visualizar los caracteres no imprimibles te recomiendo usar [este plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/52662/editor-whitespace).

El símbolo `¶` Sirve para indicar fin de párrafo.

El símbolo `>>` o `->` para los tabs (dependiendo la versión de netbeans).

El símbolo **·** sirve para los espacios en blanco.